# How to use List Class in Java When multithread is needed?

Tags: java, multithreading, list, spring-mvc

I'm using `SpringMVC`, and I've got a class `AService` which acts as a buffer to store a list of `String`, After the size of list hitting **1000**, write all of the queries into database.

```
@Service
class AService    {
    List<String> list;

    public void addAndInsert(String query)  {
    list.add(query);
    if(list.size() >= 1000)    {
        writeIntoDatabase(list);
        list.clear();
    }

    }

}
```

This will works fine when there's only one thread. But as we know that queries can be invoked from different users (that is **MultiThread** of course.), so how can I guarantee that this works properly:

1. When the query hit 1000, I'd like to use another thread to do the write-into-database, because this procedure could be long, I don't want the user to wait for something not relevant to there query.
2. The query can **not** be lost or duplicated.

Could anyone tell me how can I deal with this scenario, which implementation of `List` class should I use? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parts to my answer:

- Synchronization of adding query items to the list
- Scheduling the insert of the query data into your database

Just for completeness I will also highlight that you are open to loosing queries if your JVM crashes. You state that queries cannot be lost, but at the minute everything is being held in memory. I assume that you are OK with this.

**Synchronizing addition to the list**

Whilst a system can be inherently multi-threaded, Spring will only create a singleton of your `@Service` class, which means that all Threads access the same instance. Therefore we can quite easily synchronize access to member variables of that instance using basic Java functionality.

The JDK does provide some basic synchronized List implementations out of the box. Take a look at [Collections.synchronizedList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) or [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) for example.

These implementations generally provide synchronization for a single operation on a list e.g add() or get(). They do not provide synchronization across multiple method calls. However basic Java synchronization lets us achieve this:

```
public void addAndInsert(String query)  
{
      synchronized(list)
      {
           list.add(query);
           if(list.size() >= 1000)    
           {
                writeIntoDatabase(list);
                list.clear();
           }
      }
}
```

This code uses the [object monitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) for your List instance to ensure that all operations on it are synchronized. One Thread's operations on the list must complete before the next's.

**Scheduling insert of data into the database**

You have said that you would like to use another Thread to insert data into the database. I would suggest that you get familiar with the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) interface in the `java.util.concurrent` package. This provides excellent implementations that provide managed pools of Threads to execute tasks. From what you have said, I would suggest that [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) is ideal for what you need. It is also imperative that you remember to pass a copy of the data within the list to the other Thread so that your `List.clear()` operation doesn't interfere with the insert into the database.

So this would leave us with final code looking similar to:

```
@Service
public class AService    
{
     private List<String> list;

     private ExecutorService executorService;

     public void addAndInsert(String query)  
     {
           synchronized(list)
           {          
                list.add(query);
                if(list.size() >= 1000)
                {
                    executorService.execute(writeIntoDataBase(new LinkedList<String>(list)));
                    list.clear();
                }
            }
      }

      private Runnable writeIntoDataBase(List<String> list)
      {
          //TODO - Create your Runnable to write data to the db.

      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An ArrayList will do fine, provided all its accesses are synchronized, and you create a copy before passing it to the inserting thread:

```
@Service
class AService    {
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(1000);

    public synchronized void addAndInsert(String query)  {
        list.add(query);
        if (list.size() >= 1000) {
            List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(list);
            writeIntoDatabase(copy);
            list.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

But if it's critical that the query is not lost, you shouldn't use a buffer, because obviously, if the server crashes when the list contains 999 elements, you'll lose 999 queries.

Comment: the method `addAndInsert` will be invoked **simultaneously** from multiple threads, If I use `syncrhonized`, users would wait for some time to get the synchronized lock, don't they? This is not a good user experience I think. Is there any improvement for this approach? Thanks.

Comment: The time it takes to get a lock, add an element to an ArrayList and release the lock is negligible (a few nanoseconds), especially compared to the time it takes to send an HTTP request, wait for the server to handle it, and wait for the response. During the handling f a request, a whole lot of locks are probably acquired and released without you realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can user concurency collection like `BlockingQueue`. And another thread can get queries from collection and update database.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Robs answer, I assume you want to make sure that inserts into the DB are made for 1000 queries at once. So you can use `BlockingQueue`s (like `ArrayBlockingQueue` or `LinkedBlockingQueue`) which handle all synchronization for you. You also get methods like `drainTo`, which take a specified number of elements out of your blocking queue and return them in another collection that you can use for writeIntoDataBase. As in

```
BlockingQueue<String> list;

public void addAndInsert(String query)  {
    list.add(query);
    if ( list.size() >= 1000) {
        int size = 1000;
        final ArrayList<String> toInsert = new ArrayList<String>( 1000);
        list.drainTo( toInsert, size);
        executorService.execute( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                writeIntoDataBase( toInsert);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is a little weird. Multiple threads can enter the body of the `if` statement. I'm not sure if `drainTo` will handle this situation correctly.

Comment: You can. look at the contract for drainTo, it will handle the situation nicely. The if is provided only to avoid calling drainTo too often and prematurely.